# PhoneGap Client - Server game

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cordova

I'm going to develop client-server game using PhoneGap. Using HTML, CSS, JS in client side and PHP, MySQL on server side.

This is turn-based game multiplayer game. So the question is how can I better initiate (or emulate initiation) from server to clients, to let them now about opponent turns and when they need to move?

Have an idea to make periodic calls to server from every client. But it for example there will be 1000 clients and the delay between actions will be 1sec so I'll have 1000 calls to server/sec. It's a very high load.

What can you advice?

Comment: Look into using web sockets.

Comment: thanks, but they are not natively supported by android